# Nesting repositories and make them independently pullable/deployable?

Tags: git, github, repository

I'm not sure if the following is a reasonable thing to do (and would appreciate to be told if not) but I would like to have nested repositories with a structure similar as in my tree below.

```
github
│
└── main-repo
    ├── django
    │   ├── django-project-1
    │   └── django-project-2
    └── react
        ├── react-project-1
        └── react-project-2
```

The idea behind this is to have a centralized directory in my computer for my practice projects, easy to find, access and maintain.

I would as well like to have this same (mirroring) tree structure in GitHub for the same reasons described above, rather than having multiple GH repos.

While I can do that as a single repository with subdirectories, I would like all these sub-projects to be 'independent', meaning to be able to pull them separately, and even deploy them separately for my practice purposes.

So far I tried initializing them independently but I don't think that's doing for me what I'm looking for (i.e. I still cannot pull from GitHub a subdirectory so initialized).

I also looked at [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), but unless I'm wrong I don't think they are the right option for what I'm trying to do.

Is this a doable thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would as well like to have this same (mirroring) tree structure in GitHub for the same reasons described above, rather than having multiple GH repos.

The way to do this is to carry all the histories in the one repo and check them out as submodules. That's what you've got, and what submodules are: independently-updated histories you're interested in as part of some larger effort. The helper command doesn't have automation for this, but the setup's easy.

So here's a full reset that constructs the repo setup you describe while avoiding assuming anything about details you haven't specified here, to make the commands below work no matter what.

```
cd `mktemp -d`; git init         # we're going to build a specific branch setup
(cd /path/to/main-repo; find -name .git -prune -o -print | cpio -pd ~-)  
for d in {django,react}/*-project-*; do 
        (cd $d; git init; git add .; git commit -m-)
        git submodule add ./$d
done
```

and now you've got your nested-repos setup, but with each project added as a submodule. To hoist the histories into your main repo,

```
for d in {django,react}/*-project-*; do 
        git fetch ./$d
        git branch ${d##*/} FETCH_HEAD
done
```

and now you've got a perfectly-ordinary branch for each checked-out tip in your project repos. Edit the `.gitmodules` file and set all the url's to `./` just for the sake of cleanliness.

Now commit the result.

When you clone the repo this built, you'll get the main branch and a branch for each submodule i.e. project history. To set up the subdirectories aka projects aka project submodules,

```
git worktree add django/django-project-1 django-project-1
# etc.
```

or to automate it as was done above,

```
for d in {django,react}/*-project-*/; do
        git worktree add $d ${d##*/}
done
```

and anywhere in here you can do a `git submodule init`. Now you've got a freshly-cloned repo carrying all your independent project histories as submodules, all in one neat package.

Comment: Wow, this is a terrific explanation! Amazing! I'm trying to reproduce the steps here and get an error in the second line though: "find: illegal option -- n". Please tell me if I'm doing something clumsily :)

Comment: the only way I can see to get that is if you put a space in there, `find -name .git -prune -o -print` . . . oh. Are you on a Mac? They've got *severely* backlevel and modded versions of the gnu runtime, for now add a `.`, `find . -name .git -prune -o -print`, but do consider installing a current userland via `brew`, it will save you much inconvenience, some of it apparently gratuitously added.

Comment: I'm marking your answer as *the* solution because I trust this is the way to go. Yes, I'm on a Mac! :)  Now, after adding the dot as instructed I receive `Cannot extract through symlink (etc., long temp folder name)`...

Comment: Okay, I'm not all that familiar with Apple's userland changes, that's a cpio message, if that temp folder is the one `mktemp -d` made and it still complains? Okay, try subbing in `tar Tc | tar Cx ~-` for the cpio, maybe they've got a current-enough tar. If that doesn't work there's other ways to try, just a `cp -a` and removing all the `.git`'s after is the brute-force method. Lemme know, I'll help if you get stuck.

Comment: I appreciate your time and help enormously. I get `no matches found: django/*-project-*` (although these folders exist). I wonder if there's a more 'manual' way? I wouldn't mind doing them one by one and it's what I would still need to do as I keep adding projects to that mega folder. Again, thank you so much! By the way, I'm on zsh, if that makes a difference. (and I used cp -a, as the previous option didn't work either)

Comment: Okay, I don't understand that globbing failure at all then. If the folders exist, how do the globs not find them? Well, I thought I was stripping all the speedbump details. Wrong again.  You can try doing it by just copying your entire main-repo to a scratch folder as-is and leaving off the `git init`s in the initial setup, that might step on existing branch names, but I think you've got the idea. Clone what that builds locally, `git clone . ../test; cd $_` to see what you've got.